# centering with css doesn't work in internet explorer but does work in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

i'm trying to center a div inside a div with margin-left and margin-right. but it only works in chrome.  I already tried !DOCTYPE html but that doesn't work.

HTML

```
    <div id="footer-links">
        <div id="footer-wrapper">
            <table id="table-links">        
            </table>
        </div>              
</div>
```

CSS

```
    #footer-links {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    font-family: calibri;}

    #footer-wrapper{
    width: 1024px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

this is what it looks like in IE: http://puu.sh/kbYPO/36161cf305.png .
and like this in chrome: http://puu.sh/kbYPj/67d16bc661.png .

Comment: *uses magical sphere*  oh.. Oh yes, I can see... Uhu.. Hmm.. Yea that's annoying.. - If you don't get the hint: without any code, we can't help you. :)

Comment: i changed it.. sorry i wasn't ready yet.

Comment: It's okay well i take a look now

Comment: @ThijnLinders Please only submit questions when they're complete. :) There is no use in pressing that "submit" button early: you won't get help faster, and people downvote incomplete questions quite fast.

Comment: hmm feel weird.. still not complete. can u specify which div u wanna centerized?

Comment: the footer-wrapper div inside the footer-links div

Comment: did you already inspect the div which hold this #footer-links? I think the error come from there.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you learn something.

Updated 1.0 after being downvote sad

HTML

```
    <div id="footer">
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 30px; /* REMEMBER height = padding-bottom */
    background: #333;
}

#footer p{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

The result.

Tested in IE8

[image]

Comment: I didn't downvote you but: it might be a good idea to provide a jsFiddle with your code, so others can immediately check if it works or not. Also "try using this" can mean that you aren't sure yourself, which may lead to downvotes as well.

Comment: @Jordumus lol because the person who is asking doesnt gave enough information. And i also doesnt know where the text is coming from. At least text-align:center; should be work and set the width to 100%.

Comment: The community don't care about the question when voting for you, they care about your answer ;) if it doesn't comply with the guidelines it will get downvoted. :)